# R: Hierarchical clustering

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, hclust

Let's say we have the following dataset

```
set.seed(144) 
dat <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=5)
```

The following function creates all possible combinations of columns and removes the first

```
(combinations <- do.call(expand.grid, rep(list(c(F, T)), ncol(dat)))[-1,])
#     Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var5
# 2   TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 3  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 4   TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# ...
# 31 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# 32  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

The last step is to run k-means clustering for each subset of columns, which is a simple application of apply (we want 3 clusters in each of kmeans models):

```
models <- apply(combinations, 1, function(x) kmeans(dat[,x], 3))
```

My question is how to run Hierarchical clustering, instead of kmeans, for each subset of columns. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hclust

```
models <- apply(combinations, 1, function(x) hclust(dist(dat[,x])))
clusters <- apply(combinations, 1, function(x) cutree(hclust(dist(dat[,x])), k = 3))
```